# Getting a list of blogs entries that talks about a particular topic

Tags: php, wordpress, api, blogger

I come upon a review site that has a list of links that redirects to blog entries that talks about that particular product. How do one get these information dynamically from blogs?

I understand that Blogger has APIs but there isn't seem to be any information related to getting blog entries of a specific topic. Can someone point me into the right direction or perhaps a tutorial example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think RSS would be helpful for that matter